# Grouping ListView items from within XAML in Windows Store Apps

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, collectionviewsource

Is there a way to group collection items in the XAML code in windows store apps. In WPF you can use a `CollectionViewSource` and than use its property `CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions` or something like that, but for Windows Store apps it doesnt work. I know i can use a Linq query in the code behind, but is there an alternative that is grouping with code declared in XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not in need for an answer anymore, but I found this question while looking for something similar and also just recently stumbled across an article that probably perfectly answers your question. This might be helpful for someone else later.

[How to group items in a list or grid (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780627.aspx)

There's grouping of a ListView and querying with LINQ, just what you were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, one can group and filter within XAML using `CollectionViewSource`'s `GroupDescriptions` property and `Filter` event.  In Windows Store apps, on the other hand,`CollectionViewSource` does not have this property and event.  All is not lost, however.  Filtering and grouping are still supported, but only by feeding your `ItemsControl` (e.g. `GridView`) a collection that is already grouped or filtered.  The MSDN docs provide [step-by-step instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780627.aspx) on how to accomplish this.